# Identify this blue/red sailing club burgee

Tags: sailing

I have this picture of a sailing club burgee, found at a relatives house.

Can the club ensign be identified?

[image]

Comment: This is remarkably close in meaning to an - off-topic - autograph identification question.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. While we do accept questions seeking to identify objects, there are some exceptions, and the lack of helpful details like location and time is a deciding factor, along with usefulness to the future. I am closing this question as *lacking detail or clarity*; I think you would do well to ask a question that seeks how to identify such pennants in general.

Comment: It is the burgee of the British Motor Yacht Club. Go to the burgee registry, at www.burgees.com, and then to Group B, Page 3, Bo-Bz and scroll down until you find the BMYC burgee.

Comment: @CGCampbell that is it

Comment: Well, actually now I'm questioning that. After going to their page, the one shown there is not exactly the same. Still looking.

Comment: I think it is likely as the person who owned it used to sail there, so that is almost conclusive. But still your right it is not exactly the same.

Comment: Actually, using https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/ufe13b.html it appears to be one of the burgees of that club, so yes, I now believe that is the answer. (If the question were not closed, I'd make this an actual answer.)

Comment: @CGCampbell thank you!